# Django dropdown form submission invalid

Tags: django, django-forms

Hey i am trying to use modelchoicefield to get a dropdown list in html. But the submission of form yields a invalid form. My code is given below.
views.py

```
class SubjectSelectFormView(View):
form_class = SubjectSelectForm
template_name = 'study/select_subject.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(user=request.user)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})


def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = models.Subject.objects.get(name=form['name'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('study:quiz', subject.subject_id)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>Failed</h1>')
```

forms.py

```
class SubjectSelectForm(forms.Form):

name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.all().order_by('name'), widget=forms.Select())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(SubjectSelectForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].queryset = Subject.objects.filter(user_id=user)
```

html

```
{% extends 'basic_home_app/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<br>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Start">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try returning `render(request, self.template_name, {'form': from}` instead of `<h1>failed</h1>` when the form is not valid (same as for your `get` method except your form is bound) and add `{{ form.errors }} somewhere in your template to display the errors. That will show you what's invalid about the form. That's the preferred way anyway since users need to be able to correct their input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should always render the same template with the bound form when a posted form is found to not be valid, this way you can display errors to the user:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

Inside your template, you can display errors using either:

```
{{ form.errors }}  # all form errors
{{ form.non_field_errors }}  # form errors that aren't for one specific field, use this if you're displaying the field errors separately
```

or

```
{{ form.name.errors }}  # just the errors for one specific field
```

Second, I assume you want to initialise your form the same way when it's posted as when it's first displayed (empty) to the user via the `get()` request:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, user=request.user)  # note the user
```

Otherwise your `form.__init__()` method will set as queryset only `Subject` objects where `user_id` is `None`.